# Skipping primary key number when querying primary value before insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I suspect the answer to this is very simple, but for whatever reason, I'm a bit baffled by it.

I am trying to generate a unique 20 char alphanumeric hash value.  I have tried multiple ways to generate a random value via PHP, but I am still getting duplicates.  I was temporarily trying a process in which I query the table before the insert, pull the most recent primary key value, increase it by one and then use that as part of the generated hash value.  Unfortunately, the below code results in the following insert of the primary key increasing by 2 instead of 1 (i.e. 13, 15, 17, 19, etc.)

Here is my code:

```
$dbTableNumQuery = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ROW_ID FROM table ORDER BY ROW_ID DESC LIMIT 1");
$dbTableNumQuery->execute();
$dbTableNumRow = $dbTableNumQuery->fetch(); 
$lastID = $dbTableNumRow['ROW_ID'];
$lastID = intval($lastID);
$lastID = $lastID + 1;

$hash = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
$hash = $lastID . $hash;
$hash = substr($hash, 0, 20);

$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO secondarytable (HASH) VALUES (:hash)");
$query->bindParam(':hash', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$status = $query->execute();
```

What confuses me the most is that I don't understand why the value of the primary key is increasing by 2, when I am not specifying its value in my insert query.

And help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your auto_increment offset is set to 2, it's a MySQL config variable. Without more information, it's hard to tell if it's anything else.

Comment: It's set to 1 by default.  And when I disable the code before the insert, it increments the primary by 1.

Comment: Then it must be that one query fails and another succeeds. How about you wrap your column name with backticks? HASH is a reserved word in MySQL. Give that a shot and we can see whether it continues to increment by 2 or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have discovered the primary key skipping is due to an improperly set up semi-synced server.  We have handed this over to our server administrators.